# "How does the Shadow of The Colossus's™ proprietary (Sony's) engine perform its seamless long distance rendering?"

Tags: rendering, gpu

"How does the Shadow of The Colossus™ engine perform its seamless long distance rendering?"
[image: SS from http://www.businessinsider.com/shadow-of-the-colossus-remake-playstation-4-video-2017-9]

Comment: Perhaps if you posted an image from a different game where you feel there's a discontinuity it might make things clearer. Also, it's a bit difficult to tell from a single frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [The Making Of "Shadow Of The Colossus":](http://www.froyok.fr/documents/making_of_sotc.pdf)

> The rough algorithm is outlined below:
>
> 1. Rendering the distant view, and save it.
> 2. Foreground rendering.
> 3. Composite the distant view and foreground together. It uses the contents of the Z-buffer like a mask pattern (see image 2).
> 4. Again using the Z-buffer, generate a separate image of the mask pattern.
> 5. Reduce this to 64x64 pixels, using a bilinear filter. (This makes it ultra-low resolution.) This gets reused in step (8).
> 6. Blend in the previous frame (from step 7) using a percentage specified in the scene box.
> 7. Store the image for use in step (6). It is used for drawing the next frame.
> 8. Expand step (5) to a suitable resolution, using the bilinear filter. Thus, it becomes the material for the bloom effect where the
>    distant view starts bleeding out from the shape of the foreground.
> 9. Blend (7) and (8) using a ratio specified in the scene box.
>    [image]
>
> Landscape rendering is divided into 3 stages, the furthest background
> being either a rendered image or a texture, which is stuck on a
> distant polygon. The internal development team nicknamed this "Super
> Low".
>
> Consequently, most of the medium range which goes from nearby to
> just past the furthest background, is rendered using a low-resolution
> landscape. This is managed in units of 600x600m, and as the player
> approaches it, once he gets nearer than a certain fixed distance, it
> changes to the high-res landscape model for the foreground. This
> switch is designed to blend well so it not obvious.
>
> In addition before
> being combined down into one picture for the Super Low, most of the
> distant scenery being managed in 600x600m chunks has been reduced to
> around 1/30th - 1/100th of the polygons. Because there is little
> memory, we usually try and spread it around the landmark which
> represents that area. The combined image for the most distance scenery
> is done using this low-res model. With this, the low-resolution model
> appears seamlessly out of the Super Low image. By connecting the
> foreground and distant background well, we are able to produce a
> landscape rendering system which seems very natural.
> [image]